# PHP Kohana include problem

Tags: php, include, kohana

I am dealing with a very strange and rather simple problem about 2 days now.
I bet the solutions is obvious but i just dont know what else to do.

I am working in Kohana framework.
In my *C:/wamp/www* folder i have two different sites: mysite1 and mysite2.

So i have the fckeditor working in the mysite1 site included like this:

`include(url::base(FALSE)."static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php");  -> include(mysite/web/admin/static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php)`

and works like a charm!

Well i decided to incorporate fckeditor in mysite2, and i use the very same command..
and it just does not work and there is an erro message:

no such file or directory..

I assure you that fckeditor exists in

`mysite2/web/admin/static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php`

The full path (C:/wamp/www/mysite2/web/admin/static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php ) path include works. I just want to get include(url::base(FALSE)."static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php") working...

What could possibly be wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Kohana are you using? (Ko2, Ko3.0, Ko3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the full path works fine, but the path using the url helper doesn't work, it's probably a site configuration error.

Do any of your includes using `url::base` work?

Looking at the output of your page, what does `url::base(FALSE)."static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php"` evaluate to?

Take a look at config.php, make sure your site_domain is set up properly.

Comment: Yes the url::base works.. I have some buttons that are images and i load them as href="<?php echo url::base."/static/icons/image.png"?>" and it works just fine. Its like the fckeditor folder is not visible..

Comment: The error is like this:

An error was detected which prevented the loading of this page. If this problem persists, please contact the website administrator.

C:/wamp/www/mysite2/app_admin/views/support/view_answer.php [22]:

include(/mysite2/web/admin/static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Ckecked also the site_domain: "mysite2/web/admin". Just as it should be

Comment: Just figured that no include using url::base works..  But in my mysite1 worked just fine..

Comment: Have you tried just `include('static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php')`  or `include('/static/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.php')`?  Include uses filesystem paths, not URLs

Comment: What exactly do you mean? No i have no set something like this. If echo base::url it prints exactly what i want (/mysite2/web/admin).

Comment: @sam It worked!! Man thank you very much!! To understand this, include path is relevant to site_domain??

Comment: Well, actually it's relative to the root folder of your web site / wherever your bootstrap php file is

Answer (score 3):

When you need to include files, you can use [find_file()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/files#finding-files) method. So, your code will looks like

```
include Kohana::find_files("static", "/scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor");
```

Comment: Just checked it.. Very nice!! Thanks